# how to create a PHP function global

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to create a php file where all functions are define for my project but i don't want to include that file to every single file of my php project. i want to create all function inside that php file global so can call them in that directory. just like wordpress.

like they define most of function inside wp-include/pluggable.php which included in wp-setting.php and finally that include in wp-config.php file but i am not able to figure it out how they make that function global for theme and plugin without include it.

thanks in advance

Comment: that not my question please read it again i know how to include a function but i want to create a global function for all files without include it and found my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create global function without including the file where you defined them.
In the case of WP, the file may be included by a dependency but you can be sure it's included somewhere :)

Two way to include your file :

1. Using php native function in all your files :
   http://www.php.net//manual/fr/function.include.php
2. Using PSR standard : http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Use the PSR standard if you can.

Comment: @KevinLabécot You can call any function using the `use` keyword. ex: `use path/to/function/foo()`